# ASP.NET Core 2.1 CI/CD build error using VSTS

Tags: asp.net-core, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment

I created a brand new ASP.NET Core 2.1 project in VS2017 and then I created a pipeline with VSTS using 'ASP.NET Core' in VSTS. When the build runs I get this error all the time:

> > The "WebCompiler.CompilerBuildTask" task could not be loaded from the assembly C:\Users\VssAdministrator.nuget\packages\buildwebcompiler\1.11.326\build..\tools\WebCompiler.exe. Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'. The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the  declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are available, and that the task contains a public class that implements Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [D:\a\1\s\SukiCore\SukiCore.csproj]

So what should I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, for some reason I had this in .csproj file, so it started working when I commented it out:

```
<!--<PackageReference Include="BuildWebCompiler" Version="1.11.326" />-->
```

I think it got there when I added a new view using 'Add View' menu in the solution explorer.

Comment: Really thanks for sharing your solution here, you could mark it as the answer, so it could help other community members. Thanks for your sharing again:)